# Modal transition Tabler/Bootstrap in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm building a Tabler dashboard with some ReactJS components. At first I used normal HTML pages, with Jinja2 templates, but I started implementing ReactJS for some components.

I don't want to use too many third-party tools like react-tabler or bootstrap-tabler, because it creates a lot of extra packages which I probably don't really need. I was able to create a beautiful Tabler dashboard already, with ReactJS components, without these packages already.

The only problem I'm having now is showing up a Modal.... Now this works, but the CSS transitions don't really. At least, not at first. I got them working this way:

```
// handle button click
const handleEditClick = (row) => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
    modalRef.current.style.display = "block";

    // delay to make sure block is set first
    setTimeout(() => {
        modalRef.current.classList.add("show");
    }, 100);
};
```

The thing is, I don't really like this. It feels a bit hacky.

Showing a Modal works fine, by just first adding the `style="display:block` attribute and then adding the `show` class. This way I am able to work without much extra JavaScript or whatever. But `display:block` has to be set first. It seems that, if it doesn't, they are set simultaneously or perhaps the `display:block` a fraction later, so you won't see the transition.

I tried adding the following event listner `modalRef.current.addEventListener("transitionend", handleTransitionEnd);`, but I guess that only works fine on actually transitions and not on changing styles.

Is there a way which is a bit neater than the 100ms timeout? Obviously, I can't add `display:block` by default, because then my application is unreachable because of the transparent modal, lying on top of my application.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it right now. I use useEffect twice, which is needed to prevent the class "show" from being added simultaneously with the `display:block` style.

To close the Modal, I can actually use the `transitionend` event listener.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isButtonClicked, setIsButtonClicked] = useState(false);
    const modalRef = useRef(null);

    const [isStyleApplied, setIsStyleApplied] = useState(false);
    const [isClassApplied, setIsClassApplied] = useState(false);

    const handleEditClick = () => {
        setIsModalOpen(true);
        setIsButtonClicked(true);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const applyStyle = () => {
            if (modalRef.current && !isStyleApplied && isButtonClicked) {
                modalRef.current.style.display = 'block';
                setIsStyleApplied(true);
            }
        };

        applyStyle();
    }, [isButtonClicked, isStyleApplied]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const applyClass = () => {
            if (modalRef.current && isButtonClicked && isStyleApplied && !isClassApplied) {
                modalRef.current.classList.add('show');
                setIsClassApplied(true);
            }
        };

        applyClass();
    }, [isButtonClicked, isStyleApplied, isClassApplied]);


    const handleCloseModal = () => {
        setIsModalOpen(false);

        modalRef.current.addEventListener("transitionend", handleTransitionEnd);
        modalRef.current.classList.remove("show");

        function handleTransitionEnd() {
            modalRef.current.removeEventListener("transitionend", handleTransitionEnd);
            modalRef.current.style.display = "none";
        }
        setIsButtonClicked(false);
        setIsStyleApplied(false);
        setIsClassApplied(false);
    };

    return (
        <a className="dropdown-item" onClick={() => handleEditClick(row)} href="#">Open Modal</a>
        <EditModal row={selectedRow}  modalRef={modalRef} isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={handleCloseModal} />
    );
}
```